# For John 1:18, which of these four translations come closest to the original Greek?

Tags: john, jesus, god, image-of-god

1. No man has ever seen God, unless the only begotten Son, who is at the Father’s side, reveals him.
2. No man has ever seen God, but the only begotten Son, who is at the Father’s side, has revealed him.
3. No man has ever seen God. It is the only begotten Son, who is at the Father's side, who reveals him.
4. No man has ever seen God, but the only begotten Son, who is at the Father's side, does reveal him.

Each of the four renderings give a slightly different way of directing the passage, hence my question of trying to understand precisely which context John was trying to convey in his original writing. John 1:18 is one of the famously controversial passages, among others.

No man has seen God, unless Jesus reveals him?

No man has seen God, but Jesus has revealed him?

No man has seen God. It is Jesus who reveals him?

No man has seen God, but Jesus does reveal him?

Comment: Where are you getting these various renderings from ? Which Greek text are you using ?

Comment: Textus Receptus – and this manuscript reads *ho monogenês huios*, literally, "the only begotten Son"...

Comment: -1 and I am voting to close this question. It is presented as what I would call a strawman argument. It presents 4 options as if one of the four options must be correct. In fact, based upon the critical Greek text, none can be correct since it assumes `ὁ μονογενὴς υἱός` is original. A proper question should include `μονογενὴς θεὸς` which is accepted as original. Also it assumes the meaning of ἐξηγήσατο is "revealed." This meaning not found in lexicons. The OP asserts their own meaning. It appears from comments here and elsewhere the question is contrived to support a particular doctrine.

Comment: The Received Text _ho monogenes uios_ was long accepted until the 1800s. The alternative _theos_ makes no sense at all. It is Son (yes, divine Son, but not 'God' as such) that is begotten. The 'critical' over-emphasis on two manuscripts is not helpful.

Comment: @NigelJ The question is about which is closest to the **original** Greek. It is without dispute the question of the **original** text is in fact part of the interpretation of the verse. Regardless, the four options not only ignore what was the text it demands understanding ἐξηγήσατο as "revealed" which has no lexical support. The question should be edited or closed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two or three matters with John 1:18 that are debated:

**1. TEXT**

The text of this verse is disputed.  There are several possibilities.  Here I will list the main two with my own literal translation:

- NA28/UBS5: θεὸν οὐδεὶς ἑώρακεν πώποτε· μονογενὴς θεὸς ὁ ὢν εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρὸς ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο = God nobody has ever seen.  [The] unique God, the One being/existing in the bosom of the Father, He has revealed [Him].
- Byzantine Text/TR: Θεὸν οὐδεὶς ἑώρακεν πώποτε· ὁ μονογενὴς υἱός, ὁ ὢν εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρός, ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο = God nobody has ever seen.  The unique Son, the One being/existing in the bosom of the Father, He has revealed [Him].

For extensive details about the manuscript tradition supporting each reading and a few other readings, see UBS5 which has a huge amount of information on this verse.  Suffice to say here that the evidence points toward the UBS5/NA28 preference but is not overwhelming.  In any case, both texts lead to much the same conclusion.

Note - the Greek of this text is rather uncomplicated and simple (typical for John) and easy to translate.

2. **MONOGENES**

One of the troublesome words here is μονογενὴς (monogenes) which means, according to BDAG:

> **pertaining to being the only one of its kind or class, unique (in kind)**

See appendix below.  The word does not mean "only-begotten".

Therefore, the best, most literal English translation is that first listed above:

> **God nobody has ever seen.  [The] unique God, the One being/existing in
> the bosom of the Father, He has revealed [Him].**

Note that no conjunction such as "unless", "but", exists in the Greek.

**APPENDIX - Monogenes**

Monogenes is a word of the Greek New Testament that occurs 9 times, whose meaning is contentious because of the Arian vs Trinitarian controversy.  The contention is best illustrated by its translation in the earliest version, Jerome’s Vulgate of 400 AD.

- 3 times it applies to a parent’s only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38) and is translated “unicus”, unique.
- once it is used to describe Isaac (Heb 11:17) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.
- 5 times it is used to describe Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.

Thus, the Vulgate (both Jerome and Clementine texts) adopted an uneven practice when rendering monogenes which was followed by Tyndale, the KJV, NKJV and many more until the late 20th century.  Many modern versions since the late 20th century including NIV, NRSV, ESV, etc, uniformly translate this word as “only”, “unique” or equivalent.

The point at issue here is the cognate root of the second part of the word – is it related to gennao (beget, bear), or to genos (class, kind)?  Modern linguistic analysis (eg, see BDAG) is firmly of the view that the latter is correct.  Indeed, if the New Testament writers had intended “only begotten” then they would have used the word, monogennetos; but they did not.  This conclusion is further shown in other instances of monogenes in the LXX such as Ps 21:21 (LXX), 22:20 (NASB), Ps 24:16 (LXX), 25:16 (NASB) where the meaning cannot be “only begotten”.

Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17.  Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children.

Comment: @JoshuaB - It is rather sloppy as shown by my simple analysis above.  Further, it is not my "wishful" thing - it is that of the esteemed BDAG as well.  The translation, "only-begotten" is treasured translation that is patently incorrect by the KJV translators who depended on the erroneous Vulgate as shown above.  It cannot be correct for a number of verses as listed above.

Comment: @JoshuaB - Further, Larry Brigden is hardly a dispassionate scholar and writer, as he on the staff of the TBS and thus a vehement supporter of the KJV at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
None of the four offerings come close to the original Greek.

**No man has ever seen God**
The verse begins`θεὸν οὐδεὶς ἑώρακεν πώποτε` literally *God none has seen at any time*. Rendering `οὐδεὶς` as *no man* restricts the exclusivity.

The better understanding is ***none** has seen God at any time*.

**...the only begotten Son...**
Here we have textual variations. The critically accepted text is `μονογενὴς θεὸς`, *only begotten God* not `ὁ μονογενὴς υἱός`, *the only begotten Son*. Obviously the OP's offerings do not consider *God*.

*Only begotten God* is considered original as it is the more difficult reading and is shorter. With respect to the claims of the Gospel, since `μονογενὴς` is definite there is no reason to include the article in `ὁ μονογενὴς υἱός` unless a **scribe** had in mind the need to make a distinction between Jesus and only an child (cf. Psalm 22:21, 25:16, 35:17, Luke 712, 8:42, 9:38).

Moreover, when speaking to Nicodemus Jesus uses the term `μονογενὴς`. In the well known 3:16 He says of Himself `τὸν υἱὸν αὐτοῦ τὸν μονογενῆ`, *His Son the only-begotten*. If John intended to identify Jesus as the only-begotten **Son** with respect to God, one expects John to use what Jesus said of Himself, not coin a phrase of his own making. One of the themes throughout the Fourth Gospel is *I am...* nine times with a predicate and nine without. In my opinion it is unreasonable to believe John, who was so intent on presenting Jesus using His own words as *I am...* would introduce Him in the Prologue by simplifying what amounts to another *I am* statement. Much more reasonable is a belief *only-begotten God* is original to **John**.

Later creeds would use the phrase *fully God and fully man*. This is more consistent with `μονογενὴς θεὸς` than `ὁ μονογενὴς υἱός`.

**...the one being...**
The undisputed Greek is `ὁ ὢν`, *the one being*. In light of the nine `ἐγώ εἰμι` without predicates (cf 4:26, 6:20, 8:24, 8:28, 8:58, 13:19, 18:5, 6, 8), there is good reason to understand `ὁ ὢν` as it is used in Exodus 3:14.

Exodus 3:14 (LXX-NETS)

> And God said to Moyses, “I am The One Who Is.” And he said, “Thus shall you say to the sons of Israel. ‘The One Who Is has sent me to you.’”
> `καὶ εἶπεν ὁ θεὸς πρὸς Μωυσῆν ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ ὤν καὶ εἶπεν οὕτως ἐρεῖς τοῖς υἱοῖς Ισραηλ ὁ ὢν ἀπέσταλκέν με πρὸς ὑμᾶς`

Many claim the meaning of John 8:58 looks to Exodus 3:14 in support of Jesus using `ἐγώ εἰμι` to refer to Himself as God. By using `ὁ ὢν` in the Prologue, John effectively introduces the theme of `ἐγώ εἰμι` by recalling the name by which Moses was to give to the sons of Israel.

**...who is at the Father's side...**
The Greek is `εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρὸς`, ***in** the **bosom** of the Father*. Understanding the phrase as ***at** the Father's **side*** removes the intimacy present in the Greek. The only-begotten is **in** the Father; He is not **at** the Father. He is in the **bosom**; He is not at the **side**.

The original Greek describes the intimacy as being unique. This is consistent with the other terms *no one seeing*, the *only-begotten*, *the One Who Is*. On the other hand, *at the Father's side* implies a lesser degree of closeness which could be used of seraphim.

**...reveals Him.**
The Greek is `ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο`. Even in the unlikely case *reveals* is correct, the demonstrative pronoun gives emphasis to who is acting: ***He** reveals Him*. As is the case throughout the verse, John places emphasis on Jesus.

Very few translations render `ἐξηγήσατο` as *reveal*. The better understanding is to relate or set forth in great detail. As Robert G. Hall explains:

> The conclusion to John's Prologue is frankly puzzling: `μονογενὴς θεὸς ὁ ὢν εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρὸς ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο`, literally, 'the only God, who is in the bosom of the Father, that one has explained'. Explained what? The common translation offers an initial, satisfying solution: 'The only God who is in the bosom of the Father, that one has made him known'. The Father becomes the object of the verb; Jesus does not simply explain him, he makes him known. Now the word `ἐξηγέομαι`, at its strongest, refers to the leading out of meaning from oracular puzzles! The translations assume that Jesus for our insight leads out the Father's fullness, as an oracular priest leads out fullness of meaning from an oracular saying. Therefore, the usual translation requires a complex series of metaphorical plays. And it is successful: 'make him known' works in the Fourth Gospel. The goal of the Gospel is the readers' eternal life (20.31), and eternal life is to know (γινώσκειν) God (17.3) and Jesus does make him known (14.7, 9)
>
> However, like oracular speech elsewhere, the saying is carefully crafted to shift under the alert reader's gaze. Responsive readers will seek out the change of gestalt: `ὁ ὢν` translates naturally as 'who is' in 'who is in the bosom of the Father', but it is also the divine name (Exodus 3:14 LXX). The verb `ἐξηγέομαι`, translated 'make known' above, simply means 'to lead out' and commonly takes `εἰς`, into, followed by the destination. Recognizing `ὁ ὢν` as the divine name, 'THE ONE WHO IS' allows a natural translation of the verb: 'No one has ever seen God; the only God, THE ONE WHO IS, has himself led out into the bosom of the Father' (John 1:18). LEd whom? Responsive readers, of course (17.24).<sup>**1**</sup>

---

<sub>1. Robert G. Hall, "*The Reader as Apocalyptist*", *John's Gospel and Intimations of the Apocalyptic*, Edited by Catrin H. Williams and Christopher Rowland, Bloomsbury Publishing, 2013, p. 268.</sub>

Comment: The rendering "only God" comes from the Alexandrian texts. The rest of the texts say "only begotten Son" (monogenes hyiós). No man has ever seen God, unless the only begotten Son who is at the Father's side reveals him. End of discussion!

Comment: This article by TGC utterly demolishes your viewpoint that monogenes is not "only begotten": https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/lets-go-back-to-only-begotten/

Answer (score -1):

All the translations are compatible by using Logos as the medium to see God the father.  Philo of Alexandria first used the word Logos in Jewish philosophy. It’s the question of whether or not Jesus was the Angel of the Lord mentioned in the OT. The gospel of John uses and learned Logos in the sense as previously used by Philo of Alexandria, the Jewish philosopher.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).