Can the Greek words "monogenes huios" be translated as "precious son"?
The term monogenes is rendered "precious" in Psalm 22:20 LXX, and it seems to imply a unique, special, or darling child instead of an only child.
Isaac was not the only son of Abraham, and Jesus is not the only son of God, yet monogenes is used for both.
What are your thoughts?

This question has been discussed ad nauseam.  See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54436/isaac-and-jesus-described-with-monogen%c4%93s/54438#54438  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/92629/for-john-118-which-of-these-four-translations-come-closest-to-the-original-gre/92633#92633   https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/51140/%ce%bc%ce%bf%ce%bd%ce%bf%ce%b3%ce%b5%ce%bd%e1%bf%86-should-john-316-be-translated-with-one-of-a-kind-or-only-begotten/73096#73096  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/69939/uniquely-divine-begotten-born-one/69969#69969

See also  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47263/should-the-sense-of-the-greek-%ce%bc%ce%bf%ce%bd%ce%bf%ce%b3%ce%b5%ce%bd%e1%bd%b5%cf%82-only-begotten-vs-unique-in-john-be-und/47271#47271

@Dottard – Thank you

@Dottard – from your responses, it appears "only" or "darling" is best suited for monogenes?

@NigelJ – My question is unique in that I am specifically wondering if "monogenes" can be rendered as "darling".

The word clearly means, etymologically and comparatively, 'onlybegotten'. Otherwise one is left translating half the word - the 'mono' half (unique, solitary, only) and not translating the 'genes' part. Many argue for a weakened word but all these arguments do is demean the Son of God and demean his relationship (an eternal begetting) to the Father. Why anyone would wish to do this is beyond my comprehension.

@Nigel – Wouldn't monogenes "one offspring" imply that a particular child is special among the others? As in a precious child that is the closest to the father?

That is not the usage of monogenes in the New Testament. Luke's use of the word, in the context of several relationships, indicates no gender significance, only a generational significance and, yes, a special significance - a unique relationship. Thus the word, as used in the New Testament should be seen as a matter of generation and a matter of a unique relationship in regard to the generational relationship. Thus : only-begotten. Human relationships are used in allusion but the unique relationship of the eternal begetting (Father and Son) is what is paramount.

As is well-known, Ps 22 contains numerous prophecies about Messiah beginning in the very first verse.
V22 can be translated thus (my literal translation)

Deliver me from the sword; [and] from the power of [the] dog my unique
[life]

The matter here is how to translate יָחִיד (yachiyd) = "Only, solitary, unique, beloved".  Fittingly, its first appearance is in Gen 22;2, 12, 16, where it describs Abraham's "only son", Isaac.  See also Judg 11:34, Ps 35:17, 68:6, Prov 4:3, Jer 6:26, Amos 8:10, Zech 12;10 - the last of which is also a prophecy of Messiah.
In Ps 22:20 the word is translated in the LXX by "monogenes" (unsurprisingly) because their meanings are almost identical.
APPENDIX - Monogenes
Monogenes is a word of the Greek New Testament that occurs 9 times, whose meaning is contentious because of the Arian vs Trinitarian controversy.  The contention is best illustrated by its translation in the earliest version, Jerome’s Vulgate of 400 AD.

3 times it applies to a parent’s only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38) and is translated “unicus”, unique.
once it is used to describe Isaac (Heb 11:17) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.
5 times it is used to describe Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.

Thus, the Vulgate (both Jerome and Clementine texts) adopted an uneven practice when rendering monogenes which was followed by Tyndale, the KJV, NKJV and many more until the late 20th century.  Many modern versions since the late 20th century including NIV, NRSV, ESV, etc, uniformly translate this word as “only”, “unique” or equivalent.
The point at issue here is the cognate root of the second part of the word – is it related to gennao (beget, bear), or to genos (class, kind)?  Modern linguistic analysis (eg, see BDAG) is firmly of the view that the latter is correct.  Indeed, if the New Testament writers had intended “only begotten” then they would have used the word, monogennetos; but they did not.  This conclusion is further shown in other instances of monogenes in the LXX such as Ps 21:21 (LXX), 22:20 (NASB), Ps 24:16 (LXX), 25:16 (NASB) where the meaning cannot be “only begotten”.
Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17.  Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children.

Dottard – Interesting, thank you. Can "monogenes huios" be safely translated as "precious son"?

@OneGodOneLord - the best translation of "monogenes huios" is "unique son" which obviously makes the unique sone, precious.  However, "precious" is NOT innate in the meaning of the word.

Dottard – Ok thank you.
